# Cannot reach Object/Json

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, string, object

i´m not sure what this is, but i belive it´s Json?
`{"objekt_nr":"22133-01"}`

I try to convert it into a string like this:

```
function myFunction(objNr){
    objNr = objNr.objekt_nr;
    console.log(objNr);
```

This will result in `undefined`.

If i comment the converting part, i get: `{"objekt_nr":"22133-01"}`

How can i get this `Json`/`object`/`array` in a string, like: `22133-01` ?

I´ve also tried: `objNr = objNr[0];` and `objNr = objNr['objekt_nr']`

Comment: Can you provide more code? What is the type of `objNr` parameter – (is it string or object); Can u provide console.log(objNr)?

Comment: how did you get that object ?

Comment: Please add your call of `myFunction(...)` as well.

Comment: Is it an actual JS object, or is it a string of JSON that represents a JS object? Try `console.log(typeof(objNr));` in your function, and see what it says.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist This will say: String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is working fine. Maybe the call of `myFunction()` is wrong.

The [access of properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Accessing_properties) are:

- direct `object.property` or
- with a string `object['property']`

```js
var obj = { "objekt_nr": "22133-01" };

function myFunction(objNr) {
    objNr = objNr.objekt_nr; // i do not recommend the assignment to the former object!
    document.write(objNr);
}

myFunction(obj);
```

Edit: Suppose you have a JSON string, like `'{"objekt_nr":"22133-01"}'`, then you have to parse it first with [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). The result is an object.

```js
function myFunction(JSONstring) {
    var obj = JSON.parse(JSONstring);
    document.write(obj.objekt_nr);
}

myFunction('{"objekt_nr": "22133-01"}');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a string of JSON which represents an object. You **do not** have an actual object (yet). If you want to access properties you need to first convert it to an object, using `JSON.parse()`:

```
var objNr = JSON.parse(objNr); // create an object from your JSON

function myFunction(objNr) {
    objNr = objNr.objekt_nr;
    console.log(objNr);
}
```